# Can dmidecode command be invoked successfully by SUID program in Linux?

Tags: linux

OS is `Linux SuSE 2.6.16.60-0.21-smp`

I have one executable bin file (name is bmu) which has been configured SUID, as shown in below

`-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 14968899 2012-03-29 10:35 bmu`

And this program invoke `dmidecode` inside.

Operation will be ok if it was run by root, but `dmidecode` invoked will return null if the program was run by non-root user.

What is the reason of this problem and how to fix it?

**Edit:** Added code and description from comment:

```
read_fp = popen("dmidecode | grep 'Product Name'", "r");

/* ...... */

chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ-1, read_fp);
```

Return of `read_fp` is not null, but length of buffer is 0 which there should be some value.

Comment: Do you have SELinux on? If so try with it off, just to rule it out.

Comment: It doesn't look like that SuSE10 can support SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved in an unsafe way.

It is not enough to add SUID in the program bmu, dmidecode should also be.

`-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 59504 2006-06-16 22:08 /usr/sbin/dmidecode`

Comment: Did you find a better way?  Tho I think your workaround is still safe as it just dumps information.  I am not sure how leaking the information posts any security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The `dmidecode` program needs access to `/dev/mem` which ordinary users doesn't have permission for. The most common fix to such a problem is either to do as you already do and make the program SUID, or to add the user to the `kmem` group (the group owning `/dev/mem`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue is that I already make the program SUID, why the return of `dmidecode` invoked inside program is still null?

Comment: @siikee Can you explain what you with it "returning null"? There is no output from the command? Is the return-code 0?

Comment: My description is not accurate, the code is like this:
`read_fp = popen("dmidecode | grep 'Product Name'", "r");
......
chars_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZ-1, read_fp);
......` Return of `read_fp` is not null, but length of `buffer` is 0 which there should be some value.